# Bootstrap estimation of variance and C.I. in cases with small group of outliers

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, nonparametric, bootstrap, outliers

I have a given quantity, say $y_a$ which parametrically depends on $a$ value. I consider $N$ values for the $a$ parameter and, for each one take multiple measures of the corresponding $y_a$ (say $N_a$ measures). So I get $N$ distributions of $y_a$ for $N$ different values of $a$.
Now the quantity I really want to analize and to which I'm interested is the variance of theese distributions. I obtain $N$ values of $Var(y_a)$.
I need to get the variance associated to my variables ($Var(y_a)$) to fit them with a given theoretical behaviour and a confidence interval to judge the goodness of the fit.
I have only one variable associated with each starting distribution. So, to obtain the uncertainity intervals, I start from the original distributions, for each of them I generate a set of distributions by non parametric bootstrap (say $B_a$ bootstrap resampled distributions for the starting $y_a$ distribution); for each of them I compute $Var(y_a)_b$ ($b$ going from 1 to $B_a$).\They are the $N$ bootstrap estimate  distribution of my variable of interest $Var(y_a)$; I use them to find C.I. and variance associated.
Each of the $B_a$ copies should be, in principle, a distribution with the same number of element of the starting distribution $y_a$ (afterall we are looking for the statistics of $Var(y_a)$ which, of course, dependes of $N_a$). Proceeding in this way I obtain very narrows bootstrap distributions for $Var(y_a)$ (small C.I.).
I think the problem is in the fact that in the distribution of each $y_a$ there is a small group of outlier which has a deep impact. The fluctuation inside this subgroup, during bootstrap procedure should give the great contribute to my intervals (reflectng their deep impact). To do so, nevertheless, I think I need a huge number of $B_a$ resampling (due to the small probability to resample more of them in the same resampled "copy"). If I reduce the size of each resampled distribution the C.I. become grater (the impact of a few number of outlier resampled in the same "copy"  has a deeper impact).
So, **can I use bootastrap resampling methods with lower number of element in each resampling, using the mean value over the bootstrap copies instead of the values associated with starting distributions?**